# Где хранить данные в web-приложении?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Есть примерно такая форма, которую я сверстал на HTML и BOOTSTRAP. Суть проекта в том, чтобы можно было просматривать небольшие отчеты о проделанной работы. Приложу картинку-макет чтобы было чуть понятнее. Слева задачи, а справа появляется отчет. Каждой задаче - один отчет. Скажите пожалуйста как такое можно реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Браузер их может положить только в одно место, это LocalStorage, но есть риск эти данные больше никогда не увидеть. Поэтому в качестве хранения данных выступает серверная сторона, а не клиентская, поскольку политика безопасности браузера вас сильно ограничивает. Данные отправляются на сервер (возможно локальный и маленький) и уже он их сохраняет куда ему угодно.

Comment: @AlexKrass Хорошо. Понял. Тогда другой вопрос. Как реализовать данный вывод на экран? В каком формате хранить данные отчеты. Была идея такая: каждый отчет - новый html файл. Html каждого отчета привязываем к кнопке слева, а саму верстку отчетов в див справа, но данная идея меня не впечатляет, поэтому и спрашиваю у более опытных людей :)

Comment: Что касается визуального оформления, что можете попробовать реализовать [Bootstrap Tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior) (пример вертикального варианта в конце параграфа), правда боюсь у вас все будет в одном файле. Чтобы не писать много кода в одной файле, обычно логика перекладывается на серверную часть (данные берутся из базы данных), и дальше сервер может генерировать HTML на лету или можно использовать Ajax для запросов.